# Expression tree creation with TryParse and Convert C#

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I have a list of objects, that I want to filter by an expression which is build at runtime. The final expression contains several conditions, combined with && or ||, wrapped in clauses. Each condition looks like this:

```cs
x => x.ValueType == 1 && x.Value == "abc"
```

As you can see, there are only 2 properties to check.
If `ValueType` is 1, `Value` is always a string. If `ValueType` is 2, `Value` should always contain a string that can be converted to double.

The property `Value` is of type string.
If a condition uses a greater than (>) operator, `Value` need to be converted to double.
So in this case the expression body looks like this:

```cs
$x.ValueType == 2 & .Call System.Convert.ToDouble($x.Value) > 5
```

Until here, everything is working as expected.

The problem:

If I use the expression above (ValueType == 2 && Value > 5) with this list:

```cs
var list = new List<Item>();
list.Add(new Item { ValueType = 1, Value = "abc" });
list.Add(new Item { ValueType = 1, Value = "def" });
list.Add(new Item { ValueType = 2, Value = "25" });
list.Add(new Item { ValueType = 2, Value = "37" });
var results = list.AsQueryable().Where(expression);
```

I get a FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
I thought he wouldn't try to convert element 1 and 2 to double, because the ValueType condition already returns false. But I was wrong.

Do I need to `TryParse` all these values before converting them to double, or should I use properties for each value type instead of a single string property? I tried to insert `TryParse` in the expression tree, but I don't know how...

Changing the object model to multiple properties would cause lots of changes, that's why I want to avoid this "solution".

I am sure, someone in here knows how to handle this problem. Or at least can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&&` instead of `&` for short-circuit evaluation in C#.

```
void Main()
{
    Func<Item, bool> expression = x => x.ValueType == 2 && Convert.ToDouble(x.Value) > 5;
    var list = new List<Item>();
    list.Add(new Item { ValueType = 1, Value = "abc" });
    list.Add(new Item { ValueType = 1, Value = "def" });
    list.Add(new Item { ValueType = 2, Value = "25" });
    list.Add(new Item { ValueType = 2, Value = "37" });
    var results = list.AsQueryable().Where(expression);

    results.Dump();
}

public class Item
{
    public int ValueType {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```